# Import of matlab.engine works in IPython but not in Jupyter

Tags: python, matlab, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I just installed the MATLAB Engine API for Python to my home directory using

```
$ python setup.py build --build-base=$HOME install --prefix=$HOME
```

However, when I try to `import matlab.engine` from a Jupyter notebook, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EnvironmentError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-833daa01cd46> in <module>()
      8 import numpy as np
      9 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---> 10 import matlab.engine
     11 
     12 from dopa_net.behavioral_experiments.analysis_code import behavior_analysis as ba

/home/despo/dbliss/lib/matlab/engine/__init__.py in <module>()
     57         pythonengine = importlib.import_module("matlabengineforpython"+_PYTHONVERSION)
     58     except:
---> 59         raise EnvironmentError('The installation of MATLAB Engine for Python is '
     60                                 'corrupted.  Please reinstall it or contact '
     61                                 'MathWorks Technical Support for assistance.')

EnvironmentError: The installation of MATLAB Engine for Python is corrupted.  Please reinstall it or contact MathWorks Technical Support for assistance.
```

Oddly, I don't get this error when I `import matlab.engine` from within an IPython shell *in the same directory as the Jupyter notebook*.  Not only can I import the engine from the shell -- it works in the shell, which demonstrates to me that nothing is corrupted:

```
In [1]: import matlab.engine

In [2]: eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

In [3]: tf = eng.isprime(37)

In [4]: print tf
True
```

Any ideas what's going on?

N.B. I did install a version of the engine to my home directory earlier today, but I tried to (and thought I did) uninstall it.  My guess is some part of it has been left behind and is causing trouble.  But why is it causing trouble only for Jupyter, and not for the IPython shell?  (And how would you guess I should get rid of it?)

## Update

I tracked the error to the following line in the `__init__.py` file for the `matlab.engine` module:

```
importlib.import_module("matlabengineforpython2_7")
```

which does not raise an error in the IPython shell, but does raise the following error in Jupyter:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-831d184262c4> in <module>()
----> 1 importlib.import_module("matlabengineforpython2_7")

/usr/local/anaconda-2.4.0/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.pyc in import_module(name, package)
     35             level += 1
     36         name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
---> 37     __import__(name)
     38     return sys.modules[name]

ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /srv/local/matlab-2015a/extern/engines/python/dist/matlab/engine/glnxa64/../../../../../../../bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so)
```

I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: kind of feel like i'm losing my mind now: `importlib.import_module("matlabengineforpython2_7")` now raises an error (with a different message) in the shell -- but `import matlab.engine` still works in the shell.

Comment: ^ ah, the explanation for the above discrepancy is that the `importlib.import_module` command works in the shell only if `import matlab.engine` has previously been executed.

Comment: ^ or the path to `"matlabengineforpython2_7"` has otherwise been added to `sys.path`.  my best guess at the cause of the overall problem is that for some reason the ipython shell and the notebook don't have access to the same C libraries.  i don't know how to check or change this, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The hypothesis that the IPython Shell and Jupyter Notebook don't have access to the same C libraries seems to have been correct.  Why this is the case, I have no idea.  The two were installed as part of the same package, use the same version of Python, etc.

Adding the following line to my `.bashrc` shell configuration file fixed the issue:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=XXX
```

where `XXX` is the directory containing the version of `libstdc++.so.6` I want the Jupyter Notebook to use (and that the IPython Shell already uses).